# Removing single quotes with the variable using sed (e.g '$request_body' should be removed with the single quotes

Tags: shell, nginx, sed

am trying to remove a variable with the quotes from `nginx.conf` file

e.g: trying to remove `'$request_body'` from `nginx.conf` file with the single quotes

Thanks in advance :)

till now tried escaping the single quotes using

```bash
sed s/'\$request_body\'// nginx.conf
```

and

```bash
sed s/\'$request_body\'// nginx.conf
```

not working.

I cannot use double quotes with sed as it will try expand the `$request_body` variable.

output should remove '$request_body' completely with the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also escape `$`. In RE, `$` matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending newline. So `$request_body` matches nothing.

```bash
> echo "a'\$request_body'a" | sed s/\'\$request_body\'//
aa
```

or

```bash
> echo "a'\$request_body'a" | sed "s/'\$request_body'//"
aa
```

Comment: thanks you :) sed "s/'\$request_body'//" nginx.conf this did the job